# Search files by name - Is it possible to define the ignored characters?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS-Code you can use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> to quickly open a file.

Very often I copy a ruby class name from a stacktrace or from the code, which usually is something like `MonduleName::ClassName` (for example `Admin::User`), which by convention is located under `module_name/class_name` (in the example, would be `admin/user.rb`).

The problem is that the separator `::` is not in the file path and VS-Code does not find it, so I have to
to delete those `::` every time, which turns pretty annoying very quickly.

So the question here is pretty obvious, is there a way to tell VS-Code to ignore the `:` when performing the file search?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

I have added an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/129952) in the VS Code project, which sounded reasonable to some maintainer, but it did not get enough upvotes from the community to be implemented and got closed/discarded.

I still miss this feature, so if somebody decides to reopen it, I would be glad to get a comment here.

Comment: Damn this is exactly what I need too. I wonder if it's possible to create an extension that has its own search bar, does the text replace, and delegates to the existing search behavior and UI.